# css3 Any way to create margin or pad for individual element border

Tags: css

I have a rectangular div, it has no borders.
I'd like to create a bottom border with margin or padding.

I want to create some type of 'separator' without adding an additional element.
(if my javascript function hasn't to be rewritten)

I think that it is impossible but It could have some trick .
Any idea ? 
TH..

Comment: maybe show us some of youre code?

Comment: What do you see as an example of a "seperator"? An image, a line, etc?

Comment: @ZacWolf Yes a simple line. I know how to make it using a new div, but I want (I need) to do it using some border property. Also I can't use the div margin or padding because this div has inner elements. I'd need some as : ' border-bottom: margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px'. mmm another way could be use some 'margin or padd'' pseudo element. I'm afraid they don't exist... So only a trick can be the way?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a line, then basic CSS will work.

```
#div2underline{
  border-bottom:solid 1px black;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Play around with the values between padding and margin to define how far away the line will be from your div or any surrounding divs.

Comment: TH. but it does not make what I want. I need left and right margins for the border-bottom.(and this prop. does not exist) Finally I'm going to create new div to make that.